# Google People API with AppScript: Add People of Directory to a group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api, google-groups-api

I have a mail adress of someone in my company/domain and want to assign them a google contact label.

This is my current code:

```
function main() {
  var labelName = "Test"
  var group = getContactGroup(labelName)
  var emailAddress = "john.smith@domain.com"
  var person = getPersonByEmailAdress(emailAddress)

  addPersonToGroup(person, group)
}

function getContactGroup(labelName) {
  const people = People.ContactGroups.list();
  const group = people['contactGroups'].find((group) => group['name'] === labelName);
  return group
}

function getPersonByEmailAdress(emailAddress) {
  let request = People.People.searchDirectoryPeople({
    "query": emailAddress,
    "readMask": "emailAddresses",
    sources: ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE']
  });
  return request.people[0]
}

function addPersonToGroup(person, group) {
  var personResourceName = person["resourceName"];
  var groupResourceName = group["resourceName"];

  var membersResource = {
    "resourceNamesToAdd": [
      personResourceName
    ]
  }
  People.ContactGroups.Members.modify(membersResource, groupResourceName); //Error here
}
```

For the last statement I get the following error message:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.contactGroups.members.modify failed with error: Resource name "people/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is not a valid contact person resource.

Where is the mistake? Do I somehow need to add the person to contacts before? And also the code look a bot too complex for such an easy problem. Is there some way of optimizing it?

Bigger picture: I have a list of mail adresses of directory contacts and want to add them to a group/assign the respective label. Only people from the list should be in the group. people who are not in the list should be removed from the group.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***----UPDATE----***

As pointed out by luisa the issue might be related to the contact not actually existing, to fix this a contact can be added by the getPersonByEmailAdress() function like so:

```js
function getPersonByEmailAdress() {
  let request = People.People.searchDirectoryPeople({
    "query": emailAddress,
    "readMask": "emailAddresses,names",
    sources: ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE']
  });
  delete request.people[0]["metadata"]
  delete request.people[0]["resourceName"]
  delete request.people[0]["source"]
  delete request.people[0]["etag"]
  delete request.people[0].emailAddresses[0]["metadata"]
  delete request.people[0].names[0]["metadata"]

 People.People.createContact(request.people[0])

 return request.people[0]

}
```

The delete operator is in there because the information stored in request contains data that conflicts with the creation of a new contact such as a resourceName which is sort of a unique ID that should never be sent as a parameter for a createContact request.

***----ORIGINAL ANSWER----***
I was able to make this work by modifying the lines in

```js
 var personResourceName = person["resourceName"];
 var groupResourceName = group["resourceName"];
```

with

```js
  var groupResourceName = ["resourceName"]
  var membersResource = {
    "resourceNamesToAdd": ["resourceName"]
```

it seems like the membersResource variable requires an extra bit of data to be recognized as a resource name.

To reach that conclussion I used the [try this method](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify?apix=true) option in the documentation and selected the option to expand the view:

[image: Try this method]

There you can select "Javascript" as such:

[image]

Once there you can fill the information to the left where the "resourceName" (group resource) and the "resourceNamesToAdd" (person resource) can be filled in, doing so will add some lines to the code. From there the function we are looking for is:

```js
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.people.contactGroups.members.modify({
      "resourceName": "resourceName",
      "resource": {
        "resourceNamesToAdd": [
          "resourceName"
        ]
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

Where you can notice how "resourceNamesToAdd" actually has more information when referring to the person resource name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello,
That doesn't seem to help. I assume that it is more related to not being a contact. The person I want to add is in the directory but is not in the contact list. If I try it with contacts, and search fr the e-mailadress in the contacts, the code works.

How do I add a person from the directory to contacts?

Comment: Got it! I will work on this and add it to the response

Comment: @luisa updates to the answer have been made, could you please try and let me know if it works for you now?

Comment: Hello,
Yes this is the solution! Thanks a lot!
I modified the code so that it checks, if the user is already in the contacts. If not , the user is added as described above. Afterwards the ContactPerson is added to the group. Thanks a lot!